# Why do only some CLDR Short Names work in python?

Tags: python, unicode, discord.py, emoji

I want to add reactions on a discord bot, but only some of my Emoji CLDR Short Names work.

For example:

If I use `'\N{grinning face}'` it works, `'\N{thumbs up}'` however does not. Instead it shows this message:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-15: unknown Unicode character name

Same with `'\N{green heart}'` and `'\N{red heart}'`

I looked the CLDR Short Name up on the unicode.org page; are they just wrong or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) `\N{name}` = Character named name in the [Unicode database](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt). Use

```
'\N{thumbs up sign}'
''
```

Note that abovementioned link is to the last Unicode version (currently 13.0, I think) while your Python could use another one:

```
import unicodedata
unicodedata.unidata_version
'12.1.0'
```

FYI, excerpting from abovementioned [`UnicodeData.txt`](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt) using the `"\bheart\b"` regex gives the following:

```
Char CodePoint Description
---- --------- -----------
   ☙ U+2619    Reversed Rotated Floral Heart Bullet
   ♡ U+2661    White Heart Suit
   ♥ U+2665    Black Heart Suit
   ❣ U+2763    Heavy Heart Exclamation Mark Ornament
   ❤ U+2764    Heavy Black Heart
   ❥ U+2765    Rotated Heavy Black Heart Bullet
   ❦ U+2766    Floral Heart
   ❧ U+2767    Rotated Floral Heart Bullet
   ⺖ U+2E96    CJK Radical Heart One
   ⺗ U+2E97    CJK Radical Heart Two
   ⼼ U+2F3C    Kangxi Radical Heart
   U+1F394   HEART WITH TIP ON THE LEFT
   U+1F491   COUPLE WITH HEART
   U+1F493   BEATING HEART
   U+1F494   BROKEN HEART
   U+1F496   SPARKLING HEART
   U+1F497   GROWING HEART
   U+1F498   HEART WITH ARROW
   U+1F499   BLUE HEART
   U+1F49A   GREEN HEART
   U+1F49B   YELLOW HEART
   U+1F49C   PURPLE HEART
   U+1F49D   HEART WITH RIBBON
   U+1F49F   HEART DECORATION
   U+1F5A4   BLACK HEART
   U+1F60D   SMILING FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES
   U+1F63B   SMILING CAT FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES
   U+1F90D   WHITE HEART
   U+1F90E   BROWN HEART
   U+1F9E1   ORANGE HEART
   U+1FAC0   ANATOMICAL HEART
```

Comment: Great answer, @JosefZ. The link for specific versions of the Unicode database are available at a slightly different URL: `https://www.unicode.org/Public/12.1.0/ucd/UnicodeData.txt`. Substitute "12.1.0" with the required version; e.g., "12.0.0", "13.0.0", and so on.

Comment: @ThomasCapote thank you for good spot. The link in answer points to the current version (15 since yesterday) https://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt